# How to send checked radios values?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of items with checkboxes. I need to send that list (just as I would with a form), to a specific PHP file that erased those checked items, and returns the new list.

```
<table style="float:left;width:100%">
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <div>
            <td ?>;
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_<?php echo $item['NAME'];?>" value="<?php echo $item['ID'];?>" />
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

on the other hand I need to have a javascript function ti serialize all these values like a $_POST. 
That's:

```
    $.get("deleteItems.php", theNeededArray,   function(data){....});
```

so I need to get that array.

I know this: `var checkedItems = $("input:checked");`

contains what I need but I need to extract those **values** into an array that looks like this:

{ item_one: "cardboard" , item_two: "rabbit" , ...}

I'd love it if someone could also shed some light on the returned value of jQuery. it seems like bigger object than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form:

```
$.get("deleteItems.php", $('form').serialize(),   function(data){....});
```

Comment: nice one, never used it since with asp.net this doesnt work very well

Comment: Simple, and just what I was after, Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

you could do following

```
$("input:checked").map(function() { return $(this).val() });
```

after this you get something like this:

```
var result = ["myid1", "myid2"]
```

this is all extensable, try your self to extend to your needs